# PowerShell to fetch installed programs

Tags: powershell

I will be hosting a file on a remote server (read-only) and asking people to run the file on their machines to gather installed program information. I want the file to be saved to their Desktop in their user space, so that I can then have them send it to us.

I have the script, but I'm not managing to obtain information from both "*SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*", and "*Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*" in the same output file. I'm obviously missing something inherently obvious, as PowerShell is clearly able to do this, and I'm asking that someone please save me from my PEBKAC issue!

Thank you in advance, appreciated!

Here is my code;

```
$computers = "$env:computername"

$array = @()

foreach($pc in $computers){

$computername=$pc

$UninstallKey="SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall" 
$UninstallKey="Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

$reg=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$computername) 

$regkey=$reg.OpenSubKey($UninstallKey) 

$subkeys=$regkey.GetSubKeyNames() 

Write-Host "$computername"
foreach($key in $subkeys){

    $thisKey=$UninstallKey+"\\"+$key 

    $thisSubKey=$reg.OpenSubKey($thisKey) 

    $obj = New-Object PSObject

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $computername

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName"))

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayVersion" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"))

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "InstallLocation" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("InstallLocation"))

    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Publisher" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("Publisher"))

    $array += $obj

    } 

}

$array | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } | select ComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher | export-csv C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Installed_Apps.csv
```

Comment: Of course, this is assuming that the user will not have to run a 'powershell set-executionpolicy unrestricted' before hand.

You may be able to tell that I am new to PowerShell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the following two lines set the same variable:

```
$UninstallKey="SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall" 
$UninstallKey="Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
```

Use this:

```
$UninstallKey = @(
    'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall',
    'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'
)
```

Then wrap the real logic in:

```
$UninstallKey | ForEach-Object {
    $regkey=$reg.OpenSubKey($_)

    # the rest of your logic here
}
```

Comment: Why `ForEach-Object` instead of `foreach(stuff)`, you may ask... It's personal preference: `ForEach-Object` continues a pipeline and can process asynchronously; `foreach(stuff)` goes old-school and has to gather ALL the objects before constructing an iterator.