# How to translate this PowerShell script to C#? - Get-ItemProperty

Tags: c#, powershell

I can get a list of installed applications by using this PowerShell command:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName
```

in C#, it doesn't return the exact list like I see in PowerShell, I need it to show exactly the output from PowerShell. 
It shows a totally different list with other programs.

```
public void conf() {
process p1 = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi1 = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell", "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* | Select-Object DisplayName");
psi1.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi1.CreateNoWindow = true;
p1.StartInfo = psi1;
p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p1.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p1.Start();
string output = p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output);
p1.WaitForExit(400);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell to fetch installed programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522949/powershell-to-fetch-installed-programs)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm asking about my own code in C#.

Comment: @Mainak this is clearly NO duplicate, he has the powershell working and asks why C# using powershell doesn't output the same.

Comment: `Verb` can only be used if `UseShellExecute = true`. So that, your PowerShell instance does not work as admin.

Comment: Also notice, that in x64 operation system there are two ``HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\`` keys: one for x64 and one for x86 programs.

Comment: It worked now when I set my "Any CPU" in Configuration Manager to x64, it showed my exact list.

Comment: But how am I doing this without setting it to x64? How can I read both x86 and x64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you are talking about content - if you force C# program to run as x64 in Configuration Manager, you'll get the same output. And by default (Any CPU) it was reading from and x86 registry key. Or if you will run Powershell x86, you'll get the same result, as your original C# program

---

If you query also `HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*` key and merge results you'll get the whole list. Make sure your program is x64 in that case

There is some mess with spaces in stdout from PowerShell, so I just removed it.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lines = GetSoft("Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\*")
            .Union(GetSoft("Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\*"))
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
        lines.Sort();

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(lines.Count);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetSoft(string key)
    {
        Process p1 = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo psi1 = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell",
            key + " | Select-Object DisplayName")
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
        p1.StartInfo = psi1;
        p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p1.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        p1.Start();
        var output = p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        var result= output.Split('\r', '\n').Select(s => s.Trim()).Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));

        p1.WaitForExit(400);
        return result;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean my output had some mess with spaces, I meant it was totally different than the list I'm getting in PowerShell, I can see another programs that are installed and not the exact list in PowerShell. Weird.

Comment: It worked now when I set my "Any CPU" in Configuration Manager to x64, it showed my exact list.  But how am I doing this without setting it to x64? How can I read both x86 and x64?